# Gulp watch with browserSync

Tags: javascript, gulp, node-streams

I'm trying to write a gulp file that do the following:

1. Runs watch task that rebuilds Handlebars templates on any template change.
2. If build fails it notifies BrowserSync via notify() method so I can see popup in browser if something goes wrong. **Watch should't be stopped.**
3. If build is ok it calls browserSync.reload().

So I came up with following pice of code:

```
function SomeTask() {
  return gulp.src('*.hbs')
         .pipe(plumber())
         .pipe(somePlugin1())
         .pipe(somePlugin2())
         .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
}

gulp.watch(['*.hbs'], function(event) {
  SomeTask()
  .on('error', function(error) {
    browserSync.notify('ERROR!');
  })
  .on('end', browserSync.reload)
})
```

The problem is that if I use gulp-plumber 'end' event is emmits and browserSync.reload() is called. So I didn't see any error notification in browser.
On the other hand without "plumber" any build error breaks watch task.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gulp-plumber` let's you provide a custom [`errorHandler` function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber#optionserrorhandler). You can put your `browserSync.notify()` call in there:

```
function SomeTask(handler) {
  return gulp.src('*.hbs')
    .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handler}))
    .pipe(somePlugin1())
    .pipe(somePlugin2())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
}

gulp.watch(['*.hbs'], function(event) {
  var failed = false;
  SomeTask(function(error) {
    browserSync.notify('ERROR: ' + error.message);
    console.log(error.toString());
    failed = true;
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    if (!failed) {
      browserSync.reload();
    }
  });
});
```